# Separate event block to events by interval in full calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

app.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent = <FullCalendarComponent>{};

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'timeGridDay',
    slotDuration: "00:15:00",
    slotLabelInterval: "00:15:00",
    defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:15:00",
    selectable: true,
    select: this.selectHandler.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.eventClickHandler.bind(this),
    selectOverlap: false,
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  selected: any;

  private selectHandler(dateSelectArg: DateSelectArg) {
    this.selected = dateSelectArg;
  }
  private eventClickHandler(event: EventClickArg) {
    console.log(event.event)
  }

  addEvent() {
    this.calendarComponent.getApi().addEvent(this.selected)
  }
```

Need:
select an event (from 6:45 to 9:00), after adding it, I need separate events by my interval (6:45-7:00, 7:15:7:30...) for current example interval is 00:15mm.

**is**
[image: is]

**should be**
[image: should be]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.